# Trying to use `NativePtr.toVoidPtr` or `NativeInt.ToPointer` causes `System.TypeLoadException`

Tags: .net-core, f#

So I was trying to do some OpenGl with `silk.net` and `.net core 3.1`. When I try to convert `nativeptr<int>` to `voidptr` I get weird error.

Below is minimal example to reproduce error.

```ml
#nowarn "9"

open FSharp.NativeInterop

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let numbers = [| 1..10 |]
    use v = fixed numbers
    let v' = NativePtr.toVoidPtr v
    printfn "void = %A" v'
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This code when run generates:

```
$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: The generic type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2' was used with an invalid instantiation in assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at Program.main(String[] argv)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong version of `FSharp.Core.dll` is somehow getting loaded

Comment: @FyodorSoikin is it just my machine? I am dual booting and tried it both on linux and windows and I get the same error.

Comment: I get the same behavior. I suggest it may be an F# compiler bug, and you should open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp.

Comment: ok, thanks, I did open an issue.